# how to extend a swift protocol with an extension so that classes get an implemented variable defined by the protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

#### Circumstances

The following class:

```
class User {
    var name = "Max"
    var surname = "Mustermann"
}
```

and the following protocol:

```
protocol Sharable {
    func share(name: String)
    var isSharable: Bool { get set }
}
```

#### Intention

Extend the protocol `sharable` in a way so that subclasses of `User` get an implemented version of `share(:)` and `isSharable`.

The following extension attempts to do this:

```
extension Sharable where Self: User {
    func share(name: String) { print(name) }
    var isSharable: Bool { return !name.isEmpty }
}
```

#### Where the problem occurs

The created subclass `Admin` should get all functionality of `Sharable` for free without storing and implementing variables and functions.

```
class Admin: User, Sharable {
    
}
```

But Xcode will print the error:

> 'Admin' does not conform to protocol 'Sharable'

Xcode proposes the following:

```
class Admin: User, Sharable {
    var isSharable: Bool
}
```

Now Xcode prints the error:

> class 'Admin' has no initializers

#### Question

**Is there a way to extend the protocol `Sharable` so that `Admin` has a variable `isSharable` without defining or initializing it?** Basically like it works with the function `share(:)`, which has not to be implemented by the subclass because it is implemented by the extension.

#### Desired Call site

```
class ArbitraryObject: User, Sharable {
    // no implementation or initializing of isSharable or share(:)
}


let arbitraryObject = ArbitraryObject()
if arbitraryObject.isSharable {
    arbitraryObject.share(name: arbitraryObject.name)
}
```

Comment: It is called inheritance make shareable a class vs a protocol

Comment: `var isSharable: Bool { return !name.isEmpty }` is a computed property, you cannot set computed properties, you would need to update your protocol so that `isSharable` is only `get` and then it should work

Comment: @lorem ipsum yes, That would be a way to do it.

Comment: @Andrew please can you share how? That was a question for me, too!

Comment: Just remove the `set` from your protocol so it would become `var isSharable: Bool { get }`

Comment: @Andrew yep, that was it! Please post as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your protocol defines `isSharable` as `{ get set }`

```
protocol Sharable {
    func share(name: String)
    var isSharable: Bool { get set }
}
```

This means that when you construct your extension it is not actually conforming to the protocol

```
extension Sharable where Self: User {
    func share(name: String) { print(name) }
    var isSharable: Bool { return !name.isEmpty }
}
```

This is due to the fact that you have defined `isSharable` in your extension as a computed property. Computed properties are `get` only.

You can make your extension conform to the `Sharable` protocol by removing the `set` requirement. So your protocol would become:

```
protocol Sharable {
    func share(name: String)
    var isSharable: Bool { get }
}
```